# How to show customer name after login in their account magento 2.1.1?

Tags: magento2, login

I want to **show customer last name into my website** when customer will access their account.

```
<?php if( $isLoggedIn ) { ?>                                    
<li class="first">
    <a id="quick_sigup_link" style="positon:relative;" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/'); ?>">
            <span>Hello. User</span>
            <span class="youraccount" style="margin-top:-25px;">My Account</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using plugin and knockout

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/Plugin/Magento/Customer/CustomerData/Customer.php#L45

```
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer $subject, $result)
    {
        $result['is_logged_in'] = $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $this->customerSession->getCustomerId()) {
            $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
            $result['email'] = $customer->getEmail();
            $result['lastname'] = $customer->getLastname();
            $result['customer_group_id'] = $customer->getGroupId();
            $result['customer_group_name'] = $this->getGroupName($customer->getGroupId());
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml#L3-L5

```
<div class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
    <!-- ko if: customer().is_logged_in  -->
    <span class="logged-in"
            data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome back %1', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().lastname)">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First You need to create a object instance:

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

After That:

```
    <?php
        $customerSession = $obj->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
 echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getLastname()."<br/>";  // get Customer last name
            echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()."<br/>";  // get  Full Name

          }
```

Comment: Direct Objectmanager instance is a quick fix but should be avoided as much as possible. good idea would be to inject in the constructor.